# Can a page have two #(document).ready() methods?

Tags: jquery

i have a page which it is having $(document).ready() method.
Inside that method one more div is there which is loading another page and that page is also having $(document).ready() method in which it is adding a click event listener to an element.
But it is saying no element is present.
can anyone help in this pls..?

Script which is there in the div page:

```
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
            console.log("Entered into the page");
            var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
            console.log("Video id"+video);
            //P.E. style, let video@controls remain set if RS scripting not supported                
            //if(checkReadingSystemSupport()) video.removeAttribute('controls', 0);;
            video.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                    console.log("single click");
                    e.preventDefault();
                    togglePlay();
            }, false);

            video.addEventListener('dblclick', function(e){
                    console.log("Double Clicking");
                    e.preventDefault();
                    toggleControls();
            }, false);    

            video.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
                console.log("Key up");
                var k = e ? e.which : window.event.keyCode;
                if (k == 32) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    togglePlay();
                }
            },false);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Yes it can, it can have as many document ready functions as you'd like, and they all fire when the document is ready, but normally one such function is enough. If you're loading a different page with ajax, the javascript will not always be executed, and this is a known problem that has thousands of answered similar question here on SO.

Comment: Look into event delegation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something more like this, using jQuery as it's already included on the site :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         var video = $('video').first();
         $(document).on({
             click: function(e){
                 e.preventDefault();
                 togglePlay();
             },
             dblclick: function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                toggleControls();
            },
            keyup: function (e) {
                if (e.which == 32) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    togglePlay();
                }
            }
        }, video); // <-- delegated event
     });
</script>​​​​​​​​
```

And as noted in the comment under the question, if the javascript is in a page loaded with ajax, the browser doesn't always execute the javascript, and you'd have to either include it on the calling page as well, or extract it from the result of the ajax call and somehow execute it. If you search SO there are several answers to this already.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. Actually that div needs to be loaded dynamically and i should not edit that code as that is coming from third party. i directly has to use it as it is... :(

Answer (score 0):

You can only have multiple `$(document.ready)` calls if they are within the page source or linked in an external Javascript file.

> one more div is there which is loading another page and that page is also having $(document).ready()

Browsers don't execute any Javascript that is contained in ajax responses, that is why your `$(document).ready` isn't being called.

jQuery provides `success` events for your ajax calls, so you can add any code that you want to execute when the call was successful there.

Comment: Thank you for the response... Actually this div need to come dynamically from third party. I cant edit that div's code.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if i got it but i think you are trying to reach non existing element. If it is true just use live() from jquery. Try not to use eventlistener - IE below 8 doesn't like it.

edited: Or try to use jquery $getScript()

Comment: `.on` is the preferred over `.live` in up-to-date jQuery versions